# Private route component reproduce infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to implement Private route in react typescript but it keeps on looping. what am I doing wrong.

```
interface IComponentProps {
  [x: string]: any;
}

interface IContainerProps {
  isLoading?: boolean;
  userInfo?: any;
  getUserInfo?: () => void;
}

interface IState {
  [x: string]: any;
}

type IProps = IComponentProps & IContainerProps;

class PrivateRoute extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  state: IState = {};

  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserInfo();
  }
  render() {
    const { component, userInfo, ...rest } = this.props;
    const routeComponent = (props: any) => (
      userInfo.userId !== undefined
        ? React.createElement(component, props)
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }}/>
    );
    console.log('user info data... ', userInfo);
    return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent}/>;
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

I am not sure what might be the problem here. It keeps redirecting to the login page even though the login is successful.

Comment: what does userInfo print for you in the component

Comment: It prints a payload object. like  userInfo{username:"", email:"", userId:"",}

Comment: is login re-rendering or is it just not going away? Do you see the login screen flash and input fields clear?

Comment: @FujiRoyale it is re-rendering. I do not see the login screen flash, I can only see the url route keeps changing

Comment: url changes from what to what? And is it doing it without any interaction from you?

Comment: @FujiRoyale yes without any interaction, it's changing from login to dashboard

Comment: @Paul - ok so this seems like it could be related to state updating as a result of the state updating. I'd checkout what is happening with this.props.getUserInfo();. Also not sure if you need the async on the componentDidMount(). So maybe try without (though that may cause TS to complain.  Good luck.